# ValueError: cannot add indices of unequal length (using Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, plot, func

I'm going through the Python notebook here:
https://github.com/gianlucahmd/loads_clustering/blob/master/loads_clustering.ipynb
and get to the line:

```
plot_range(path, "2004-01-04", "2004-12-31")
```

which then generates a

```
ValueError: cannot add indices of unequal length
```

error. 
Does this have something to do with pandas/tseries/index.py, pandas/tseries/index.py??

Many thanks, 
Nic

Comment: The only print statement on the nb you linked to looks like 3.x syntax.  Are you trying this on 2.7 or 3.x?  Just a thought.

Comment: Hi TMWP, I'm doing everything with 3.x - Thanks!!

Comment: If you have a Python 2.7 secondary environment, you may want to try the code there and see if it works.  If so, this is a case of code that needs to be changed for version compatibility.  The future warnings showing on this notebook make me suspect the code may have been written for 2.7 which means you may have to do some 3.x compatibility edits to get past the errors you are seeing.  Alternatively, set up a secondary environment for Python 2.7 and you can first run the code as it was intended, and then look into how to fix it.  Just ideas. I haven't worked on this specific code

Comment: one more thought in case you have to debug in 3.x:  the error usually indicates the values passed to x and y are two lists that do not contain the same number of elements.  This causes the code to fail because it can't plot each point unless there is an x,y pair for each and one or more of them would be missing an x or a y if the lists are uneven.  Try viewing the two indices to see what is getting passed in.

Comment: You may also want to investigate if NAs exist in the data which could result in some records having a missing x or y.  Since 2.7 and 3.x sometimes handle NAs differently, what works in one may break in the other.  Again - these are just ideas.  Hope they help.